# Win32 c++ resize createwindow at runtime

Tags: c++, button, window, runtime

I write in win32 api c++, and use mingw.
I would like to resize a button when the main window is resized at runtime.
Here is my code:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
 // BLA BLA BLA
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        szClassName,
        "Main Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        800,        // width
        1000,       // height
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );
  // BLA BLA BLA
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
         RECT  rect;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        int width = rect.right - rect.left;
        width = width-20;

        HWND button = CreateWindowEx(BS_PUSHBUTTON, "BUTTON", "grafikon",
                           WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                           10, 10, width, 25,
                           hwnd,
                           (HMENU)ID_BUTTON,
                           GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                           0);
      // BLA BLA BLA
}
```

So I would like to resize the BUTTON at runtime. How can I do this? 
thanks

Comment: What part are you having trouble with, resizing it or doing it when the main window is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you search WM_SIZE MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646.aspx